# How do I get the keys for the Evil Spirit Club Floor 2?

Tags: persona-q

To get through the second floor of the Evil Spirit Club you need to get two keys again. These seem to be a similar puzzle. What do you have to do to get the second set of keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the keys for this floor you have to do a few things. They are much more straightforward than the first floor but it involves a little bit more back and forth.

- First you need to find the power switch. You cannot turn it on yet (or else it would be too easy.) It is located at a dead end on the north west side of the floor:

> Zone B2(E1 of that zone) is the exact location.

- This will direct you to the "Reference Room". The Reference Room is located in the room at the corner of:

> C4,C5,D4,D5. You will see a bunch of newspapers on the ground that call out the room as such.

- In the reference room you will find newspapers and you will find instructions that tell you in what directions to travel in order to accomplish something. The exact location these instructions start from is not mentioned and it is your job to find them.
- There is a dead end that you come across that has an arrow pointing downwards. This is the starting point for those directions. At least for me the directions started at:

> Zone B4(C2 of that zone)

- If you follow the directions starting from that point you will come across a few new messages and eventually "hear something". This is the switch gaining power.
- Now you can return to the original power switch and turn the lights on.
- From here the key to the Lab Storage Room is location 3 spaces away at

> B2(D4). I believe it is found automatically but if not spin around until "Check!" shows up.

- After this you can explore are normal and inside of the Lab Storage area the key to the South Building can be found within. Again the second key does not involve a puzzle. It can be found at:

> Zone D1(C3)